# How to generate amplitude and Phase values (I,Q) for 8 QAM?

Tags: constellation-diagram

I am trying to simulate 8QAM with (4,4) amplitude levels. I want to get a constellation like this:

[image]

What are the amplitude levels should I select for I and Q?

Comment: notice the `001`, `010`, `110`, and `101` all form a square and notice `001`, `101`, and `011` form an equilateral triangle.  that should give you an idea what the relative amplitudes are.  the angles for all of the points in the constellation are multiples of 45°.

Comment: Also note that there are good reasons why this constellation is NOT commonly used. And the complicated decision boundaries are among those. So if you ask me, you "should" use amplitude levels that distort this constellation to look like a psk.

Comment: You can simply write a look-up table that maps tuples of 3 bits to in-phase and quadrature amplitudes.

Comment: @MBaz I tried, but I eneded up getting error in Simulinik. Can you give me the exact lookup table that I can map the values?

Comment: @banureddy That's a different question -- you don't mention simulink at all in your question. I don't use simulink.

Comment: This requires just a bit of regular math. For example, point 001 maps to I=-1 and Q=1. You should be able to find other points like that. You should be able to find the height of the equilateral triangle by yourself.